# MySQL mod vs PHP mod

Tags: php, mysql, modulus

**Edited**
Sorry guys I want PHP mod to display decimals

In MySQL `select mod(15.6,1)` result `0.6` but in PHP `15.6 % 1` result `0`?

My purpose is to restrict calculation only for exact integer which does not allow decimals

Comment: It's not clear from your question what your goal is, nor why you'd expect the PHP interpreter to behave like MySQL. Do you want the modulus operation to return a real number or an integer (regardless of input)?

Comment: Whose mode behavior do you want here, MySQL or PHP?

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, the `%` modulus operator works on integers. The operands 15.6 and 1 are cast to int (15 and 1) before being worked on. Therefore, 15 % 1, as you may expect, gives 0. Therefore "exact integer which does not allow decimals" matches the behaviour in PHP.

In MySQL, as the documentation says:

> MOD() also works on values that have a fractional part and returns the exact remainder after division

Therefore, you should TRUNCATE(operand, 0) the operands before using them in MySQL to obtain the integer behaviour. This is consistent with PHP's behaviour of casting to int -- numbers are truncated, not floored (which is a significant difference with negative numbers).